Wavelet admissibility and orthogonality
I have been studying the continuous wavelet transform and came across the following result on the Wikipedia:
A wavelet $\psi(t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is admissible if it has a finite, strictly positive admissibility constant, $0 < C_\psi < \infty$, where $C_\psi$ is defined to be:
$$C_\psi := \int_{-\infty }^\infty{\frac{\overline{\mathcal{F}\{\psi\}(\omega)}\mathcal{F}\{\psi^{*}\}(\omega)}{|\omega |}}d\omega $$
Where $\psi*$ is the dual of $\psi$, or "dual wavelet". If $\psi = \psi^{*}$ (self-dual) then $C_\psi$ becomes:
$$C_\psi := \int_{-\infty }^\infty{\frac{|\mathcal{F}\{\psi\}(\omega)|^2}{|\omega |}}d\omega$$
($\mathcal{F}$ is used to denote the Fourier transform operator)
I understand that a wavelet being a “dual wavelet” is equivalent to being orthogonal, but I cannot find any connection online between admissibility and orthogonality / being self dual. I also understand there maybe both weak and strong admissibility from some sources I have read, but I cannot find much material on what the distinction is.
Could anyone provide some clarification on this result, and ideally a source of where this comes from, thanks.

What do you mean by "connection"? What kind of connection are you seeking?

How are these things supposed to go together? The admissibility criterion is for continuous WT, while duality/bi-orthogonality and orthogonality are properties of discrete wavelet transforms and their affine frames. // I once edited in the suite of wavelet articles, it was a mess then, but not reformable as too many people had too many different opinions on what the primary topics are that define the structure of the articles. You will get better results with the original sources (which are the most reliable part of wikipedia articles).

@LutzLehmann I'm only quite new to this topic but from what I have read, a wavelet being self dual (where the analysis and synthesis wavelet are identical) is equivalent to wavelet orthogonality. I understand continuous wavelets can't be orthogonal, although I don't quite understand why. I have read somewhere that a wavelet is orthogonal if it's $L_2$ inner product with its daughter wavelets is 0, and its $L_2$ norm is $>0$. I have been reading Wavelets: An Analysis Tool by M.Holschneider and page 65 mentions the first admissibility criterion, although I can't find reference to it elsewhere?

@StefanLafon When papers or books make use of the admissibility criterion, they practically all exclusively use the second condition and I can't seem to understand why given that there is no assumption made on whether the discussed wavelets are self-dual. Is the first equation redundant in some way?

Daubechies' "10 Lectures" are a good introduction, spanning from practical to theoretical. Anything from her student/collaborator Christopher Heil should also be good. Anything along word combinations of "Tight frames of compactly supported affine wavelets" deals with how discrete samplings of continuous wavelet scaleograms relate to discrete wavelet transforms. The other direction of how to use discrete wavelet transforms to compute suitable approximations of scaleograms might also be insightful.

@LutzLehmann Thank you for the recommendation; I fear I may be getting out of my depth quite quickly here, but I will definitely look into it further.

How much theory you need really depends on what you want to do with wavelets. Of the admissibility one practically only needs to know that taking any reasonable function $f$, and setting $\psi(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ usually results in a wavelet function. It requires some effort to get counter-examples. With scaleograms the more practical question might be how to read them (and how to automate this analysis). Qualitative results,shapes etc., should not overly depend on the wavelet used, quantitative results, how a feature gets distributed along the scales, might depend.

@LutzLehmann I'm just writing a paper on wavelet transforms in general and some of their properties, and I have found the language quite confusing in many places...

A problem seems to be that wavelets never really took of application-wise. It is a nice theory, but the implementation complexity provides a threshold. If you consider the DCT as the most basic wavelet transform in generalization of the Haar wavelet, then it is the most efficient one and sufficient for almost all applications. For instance JPEG and associated movie formats are 8-channel DCT with post-processing, wavelets were tried but not widely successful. The core group of wavelet research at one point abruptly switched to compressive sensing. The site wavelet.org does not exist any more.
